# Why am I getting this Paypal create order error?

Tags: javascript, json, paypal

When I run this code and click the Paypal button, I get the following error:

> err: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map'

Any idea why this is? As far as I can tell I formatted it correctly. (Obviously I replaced MY_CLIENT_ID with my client ID).

I am working on the assumption that this doesn't need any server-side code to support it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?currency=GBP&client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<!-- Add the checkout buttons, set up the order and approve the order -->
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
return actions.order.create([{
"purchase_units":{
"reference_id":"HOP_6rN2fD3oyM",
"description":"Hop Music Lesson Purchase",
"custom_id":"HOP_6rN2fD3oyM",
"soft_descriptor":"HOP_6rN2fD3oyM",
"amount":{
"currency_code":"GBP",
"value":"36",
"breakdown":{
"item_total":{"currency_code":"GBP",
"value":"36"}}
},
"items":[{
"name":"Single Lesson, In-Person: 45 mins",
"description":"Single Lesson, In-Person: 45 mins",
"sku":"45MIN_SINGLE_INPERSON",
"unit_amount":{
"currency_code":"GBP",
"value":"36"},
"quantity":"1",
"category":"DIGITAL_GOODS"
}]
}}]);
},
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
});
}
}).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Display payment options on your web page
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "category":"SINGLE"

Not sure if this is your specific issue, but this is not a valid category so a map error would make sense. [See here for the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item)

> **category** *enum*
>
> The item category type. The possible values are:
>
> - `DIGITAL_GOODS`. Goods that are stored, delivered, and used in their electronic format.
> - `PHYSICAL_GOODS`. A tangible item that can be shipped with proof of delivery.

Comment: Ah, nice spot, thanks. But this doesn't fix it unfortunately. Updated code above.

Comment: Ok running your code, in the console the real error is "purchase_units is undefined".  You have the wrong array and object structure, which would be much easier to notice if your code was indented properly.  See the sample at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client for comparison

Comment: I don't receive that error when I run the code. I'll compare to the sample to see if there is a difference.